# Android broadcast to specific 3rd party applications

Tags: java, android, android-broadcast

I developed an android app and it sends broadcast with a custom permission.

```
public abstract void sendBroadcast (Intent intent, String receiverPermission)
```

Now any 3rd party app that has a broadcast receiver and declared the custom permission in their manifest will be able to listen to the broadcast.

Is there a way to control which application can receive the broadcast from my application?

what I'm afraid of is the custom permission gets in the hand of the wrong people and they start creating their own app to listen to my broadcasts.

FYI, the protection-level is set to dangerous.

Thanks,

Comment: If you don't want apps listening to the broadcast, why are you sending one in the first place? What is the purpose of this broadcast, and what is your decision-making process as to which developers are and are not allowed to listen for it?

Comment: The intent is to be broadcast to only to a few selected 3rd party app.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can set the receiving package name of the 3rd party app in your intent as follow:

```
intent.setPackage({3rd pary app package name});
context.sendBroadcast(intent);
```