# An app that launches shortcut to other app onclick?

Tags: android

I have a situation where I would like a separate apk that launches a shortcut to another app onclick.  I have accomplished this with Tasker and it works ok, but it is slow and clunky.  I want it to launch a terminal command or intent like below:

am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n "package"/"activity";"extras"

Or

## Intent;action=android.intent.action.MAIN;launchFlags=0x14800000;component="package"/"activity";"extras";end

I am not a programmer, but can usually fiddle with code until it does what I want.  Is there a simple app source I can basterdize to accomplish this?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In Android you do this by sending an intent.  You can send it to a specific app.

See [Android broadcast to specific 3rd party applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26023829/android-broadcast-to-specific-3rd-party-applications)

If you want to launch your own separate application, you can create a new intent.  Otherwise, you can certainly send the "android.intent.action.MAIN" intent.